# Javascript singleton accepting arguments

Tags: javascript, parameters, arguments, singleton

So there are a lot of questions and answers about the **singleton pattern** and JavaScript already. But still I couldn't (easily) find a good answer that showed a singleton *that accepts arguments*. So let's try and change that.

So this is one I came up with:

```js
Global = {};

Global.Singleton = (function () {
    var instance  = undefined;
    // The returned object (Global.Singleton):
    return {
        getInstance : function (name) {
            if (instance) return instance;
            //===========================================|
            // The 'constructor' function:
            return (function (name) {
                var _name = name;
                instance = {};
                instance.getName = function () {
                    return _name;
                };
                return instance;
            }(name));
            //===========================================|      
        }
    };
}());  

(function () {
    var instance = Global.Singleton.getInstance("Chuck");
    console.log(instance); //  Object { getName=function() }.
    console.log(instance.getName()); // Chuck.
    console.log(instance === Global.Singleton.getInstance()); // true.
}());
```

Is this a good design?
(I am not yet a professional, so hopefully some experienced programmers will confirm whether this is good or bad code.)

Perhaps you have an alternative and want to post that too here?

**EDIT:**
I don't know what i was thinking, but the above code can just be simplified to this (which probably is already on this site a thousand times):

```js
Global = {};

Global.Singleton = (function () {
    var instance  = undefined;
    // The returned object (Global.Singleton):
    return {
        getInstance : function (name) {
            if (instance) return instance;
            //===========================================|
            var _name = name;
            instance = {};
            instance.getName = function () {
                return _name;
            };
            return instance;
            //===========================================|  
        }

    };
}());  

(function () {
    var instance = Global.Singleton.getInstance("Chuck");
    console.log(instance); //  Object { getName=function() }.
    console.log(instance.getName()); // Chuck.
    console.log(instance === Global.Singleton.getInstance()); // true.
}());
```

Comment: I would encourage you to have a look at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Seems like another great resource. But I don't understand what exactly makes it different from this site?

Comment: This site is for helping programmers solve problems, and find solutions. What makes it different from codereview is that most questions can be relevant to other people in the future, if they find themselves in the same situation. Codereview is all about code quality (design, performance, good practices). I believe this is where your question should be (but that is just my opinion, you can keep your question here and see what happens).

Comment: But we prefer questions with context at Code Review... and this doesn't have a whole lot of context. Its example code and would get closed. Try Programmers if you want to know about a design pattern on a higher level, keep it on Stack Overflow if you're looking for a good example implementation of a singleton in JS.